# How to combine the attributes in jsoup selector

Tags: java, jsoup, selector

I have parts of html for parsing:

```
<a href="/res/" class="postbtn-reply-href" name="112309691"></a>
<blockquote id="m112309691" class="post-message"> text </blockquote>
```

How can I do it with different attributes?

- for `<a>` attribut is ["name"]
- for `<blockquote>` it is text()

something like:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("a [class=postbtn-reply-href]["name"], blockquote[class=post-message] [text()]");
```

Comment: `text()` is not actually an attribute name.

Answer (score 1):

What about this CSS selector?

```
a.postbtn-reply-href[name], blockquote.post-message:contains(text)
```

DEMO: http://try.jsoup.org/~kPbUK0RX6brMZFZZH-U-u9yVukY

---

The initial CSS selector is understood like below by Jsoup:

```
a                              // Select node descendant of a anchor node (a),
[class=postbtn-reply-href]     // having a class named postbtn-reply-href
["name"]                       // and an attribute called "name"
,                              // OR
blockquote[class=post-message] // Select a node descendant of any blockquote having a class named post-message
[text()]                       // and having an attribute called text()
```

**References:**

- [Jsoup Selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)
- Jsoup 1.8.3

Answer (score 0):

try this (element.class-name)

```
   doc.select("a.postbtn-reply-href[name=112309691]")+""+doc.select("blockquote.post-message").text();
```